Insights for Outcome Function Involving Multiple Interdependent Variables
I am working on a model involving multiple interdependent variables and systems of equations, and I am trying to gain insights into the behavior and properties of a specific outcome function. Despite linear and rather simple model setup (not covered here in detail), I have run into very complex issues which I do not know how to solve.
I have even tried comparative statistics to gain some insight into the model, but since the model is very flexible and there are no natural or mathematically strict enough parameter spaces, the model's main insights in rigorous form remain out of my reach. Below I roughly outline the setup and the equations characteristics involved.
Setup of two systems of equations
Given some initial parameters, I try to find 4 variables and derive the 5th given the parameters and one of the 4 variables. Here I obtain variables
$$[x_a, x_b, y_a, y_b, y_c]$$
from parameters
$$[\alpha, \gamma, \pi, \lambda, \eta], \in \mathbf{R}_+$$
given some functions.
There are two systems of equations initally which need to be solved numerically since no neat or clean enough closed form solutions exist. I know that there are some closed form solutions but they cannot be written out to any paper due to their lengthiness.
$$\begin{cases}
h_1(x_a, \gamma, \alpha, \pi, \lambda, \eta)&=h_2(x_b, \gamma, \alpha, \pi) \\
h_3(x_a,\gamma, \pi, \lambda)&=h_4(x_b, \gamma, \alpha, \lambda)
\end{cases}
$$
Then the second system of equations has rouhgly the same structure:
$$\begin{cases}
j_1(y_a, \alpha,  \lambda, \eta)&=j_2(y_b, \alpha, \pi, \lambda) \\
j_3(y_a, \gamma, \pi, \eta)&=j_4(y_b, \gamma, \pi, \alpha, \lambda, \eta)
\end{cases}
$$
Note: $h_i \neq h_j \forall i\neq j$ and $j_i \neq j_k \forall i\neq k$ and also $h_i \neq j_k \forall i\neq k$.
And given the solution of $y_b$ the following can be derived:
$$y_c = j_5(y_b, \pi,\lambda)$$
Setup of the outcome function
Now the outcome function will have the aforementioned variables
$$[x_a, x_b, y_a, y_b, y_c]$$
which have probabilistic behaviour under the model assumptions and they also have an inequality which they need to satisfy under all conditions (incl. the probabilistic behaviour):
$$0<y_a < x_a < x_b < y_b < y_c < \lambda \le 1$$
The outcome function also takes parameters which were also used to find the variables $[x_a, x_b, y_a, y_b, y_c]$:
$$[\alpha, \gamma, \pi, \lambda, \eta] \in \mathbf{R}_+$$
This give a vector of parameters and variables for the outcome function $f$ as follows:
$$\mathbf{v}=[\alpha, \gamma, \pi, \lambda, \eta, x_a, x_b, y_a, y_b, y_c]$$
Outcome function and its $\Delta$ near $0$
The outcome function is just
$$y=f(\mathbf{v})$$
I can hint that this model was used for economic analysis and the $f(\mathbf{v})$ is roughly welfare change when certain economic actors are included to the system, so what is also of interest is the behaviour of the outcome function very near zero, $f(\mathbf{v})=y\in[-\varepsilon, \varepsilon], \varepsilon \to 0$.
How should I analyze the behaviour of $f(\mathbf{v})$? I have tried fixing some of the parameters and creating relations like $\gamma=0.1\alpha$ to allow reducing the number of free parameters in order to provide easier simulation results or allow to draw more intuitive plots etc. The lack of natural parameter spaces just makes comparative statistics so much more meaningless, that I would prefer finding a way to characterize the function itself in a more insightful way.
There are some quadratic relations in play, but nothing exponential or such (not that it really matters). I have been thinking about mapping the problem into optimization issue via Hessian matrix, but with very little success since the definitiveness needs once again some actual parameters if it was to be calculated. Maybe normalized partial derivatives could be of use, or differential equations as a whole? I just don't see the road map of using those.
In short: what kind of tools could be used to analyze functions which have parameters and variables as inputs and when there are more free variables than natural dimensions?

If the parameters involved are random, then variance-based techniques such as Sobol indices may be fruitful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-based_sensitivity_analysis

@whpowell96 I have done some work with brute force grid search so I kind of know what sort of parameters would be needed to make the model work given the inequality conditions. Only thing I don't like is that the model is very, very volatile if linear relationships between variables are not established. The reason why the partial derivatives only provide "on the other hand" information is the same why the sampled data is very volatile wrt. to sensitiviteis and causalities. In pure sense, the parameters are not random, but allow to sample for scenarios. But I will take a look on that, thanks!
